# How to group by and return values from each group?

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm

I have such table

```
id p_id number 
1   1   12 
2   1   13
3   2   14
4   2   15
```

How to get such items in my view,
i mean group by p_id and get number values from the group

```
for p_id 1 returns count 2 and 12,13
for p_id 2 returns count 2 and 14,15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `values()` and `annotate()` to group, so:

```
from django.db.models import Count
pid_group = YourModel.objects.values('p_id').annotate(ncount=Count('number'))
```

After that you will get a list of dicts `pid_group` like this:

```
[{'p_id': 1, 'ncount': 2}, {'p_id': 2, 'ncount': 2}]
```

You can get the number value easily then:

```
for pid in pid_group:
    number_values = YourModel.objects.filter(p_id=pid.get('p_id'))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good, but might be more efficient to get the objects and process and group them in memory.